# react immutability helper to render only changed subset of data

Tags: reactjs

Please see the example here  http://jsfiddle.net/8xzxkteu/1/

I'm trying to only render part of the data which is changed. In this example, state of component `Main`, `data`, is indexed by `id` and I am using react immutability helper to set only the changed one. But, if you click on the output, it renders all the children, as indicated by the counter. I though using immutability helper react can detect only part of the data changed hence only render it. I probably could use `shouldComponentUpdate` and compare object values for each child, but is there a better way doing this with immutability helper.

```
 class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this)
      this.state = {
            count: 0
      };
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        var count = this.state.count + 1;
        this.setState({ count: count });
    }

    onClick() {
        this.props.onClick(this.props.name);
    }

    render() {
        return <p onClick={this.onClick}>{this.props.name}: {this.props.value} {this.state.count}</p>;
    }
  }

  class Main extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
      this.state = {
            data: {
                "a" : "a",
              "b" : "b",
            }
      };
    }

    handleChange(id) {
      this.setState({
        data: React.addons.update(this.state.data, { [id]: { $set: 'x' } })
      });
    }  

    render() {
      const keys = Object.keys(this.state.data);
        const children = keys.map(k => {
            return <Child name={k} value={this.state.data[k]} onClick={this.handleChange}/>
        })
        return <div>
            {children}
          </div>;
    }
  }

  React.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: Remember that when `Main` re-renders, all children will re-render as well. You definitely need to use `shouldComponentUpdate` in the `Child` to check whether it should re-render or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change state of component react call `shouldComponentUpdate` of this component and if it is return `true` react call render of this component.

After that react call `componentWillReceiveProps`, then `shouldComponentUpdate`, then `render` (if `shouldComponentUpdate` return true) of *all* child component.

By default, if there no `shouldComponentUpdate` method, it is considered that it has returned `true`. It does not matter whether you use immutable data or not - react does not know about it.

If you have immutable data you want avoid rerender, you should use `shouldComponentUpdate`. You can use [pure-render-decorator](https://github.com/felixgirault/pure-render-decorator), for example – it's check component state and props.

But if you change your state in `componentWillReceiveProps` you still get rerender because `componentWillReceiveProps` is called before `shouldComponentUpdate`.